# Ray Tune: How to optimize one metric but schedule (early stop) based on a different one?

Tags: hyperparameters, ray, ray-tune

I'd like to use Ray Tune to optimize for `metric_slow`, but, since that takes a long time before it is available, to use ASHA to early stop based on `metric_fast_but_rough`.  I tried to do this by giving `scheduler` one metric and `tune.run` a different one, setting `TUNE_DISABLE_STRICT_METRIC_CHECKING`.  However, I got the following error:

```
You passed a `metric` or `mode` argument to `tune.run()`, but the scheduler you are using was already instantiated with their own `metric` and `mode` parameters. Either remove the arguments from your scheduler or from your call to `tune.run()`
```

How can I tell Ray Tune to **optimize one metric but schedule (early stop) based on a different one**?

Answer (score 0):

Does the following work for you?

```
from ray import tune
from ray.tune.search.optuna import OptunaSearch
from ray.tune.schedulers import ASHAScheduler
from ray.tune.search import ConcurrencyLimiter


def my_objective(config):
    # Hyperparameters
    width, height = config["width"], config["height"]

    for step in range(config["steps"]):
        # Iterative training function - can be any arbitrary training procedure
        your_calculation_here()
        # Feed the score back back to Tune.
        tune.report(
           iterations=step, metric_fast_but_rough=metric_fast_but_rough, metric_slow=metric_slow
        )

searcher = OptunaSearch(metric="metric_slow", mode="max")
algo = ConcurrencyLimiter(searcher, max_concurrent=4)

analysis = tune.run(
    my_objective,
    search_alg=algo,
    num_samples=8,
    scheduler = ASHAScheduler(metric="metric_fast_but_rough", mode="max", max_t=10, grace_period=1, reduction_factor=2),
    config=config,
)
```